# Converter um objeto que implementa a interface, na sua própria interface

Tags: c#, interface

Fiz o seguinte código:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        //Este método funciona
        Metodo(new ClasseTeste(){ Obj = new Registro(){ Nome = "Nome Teste"}});

        //Este não
        Metodo2(new ClasseTeste(){ Obj = new Registro(){ Nome = "Nome Teste2"}});

        //Este não          
        Metodo3(new ClasseTeste(){ Obj = new Registro(){ Nome = "Nome Teste3"}});

    }


    public static void Metodo<T>(IBase<T> parametro) where T: class,IRegistro
    {
        string nome = parametro.Obj.Nome;
        Console.WriteLine(nome);
    }

    public static void Metodo2(IBase<IRegistro> parametro)
    {
        string nome = parametro.Obj.Nome;
        Console.WriteLine(nome);
    }

    public static void Metodo3(Teste<IRegistro> parametro)
    {
        string nome = parametro.Obj.Nome;
        Console.WriteLine(nome);
    }
}
```

Registro:

```
public interface IRegistro
{
    string Nome {get;set;}
}

public class Registro : IRegistro
{
    public string Nome {get;set;}
}
```

Interface genérica e implementação:

```
public interface IBase<T> where T : class
{
    T Obj {get;set;}
}

public abstract class Teste<T> : IBase<T> where T : class, IRegistro
{
    public T Obj {get;set;}
}

public class ClasseTeste : Teste<Registro>
{

}
```

O Primeiro método `Metodo` funciona, os outros dois não.

É retornado o seguinte erro:

> `Cannot convert ClasseTeste to IBase<IRegistro>`

**Pergunta:**

Porque não posso converter um objeto que implementa a interface, em sua própria interface ?

Coloquei no [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ga7saH)

**Edit:**

Após ler sobre [*Variância em interfaces genéricas (C#)*](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/variance-in-generic-interfaces)

Alterei o código, para uma interface covariante:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        Metodo(new ClasseTeste(){ Obj = new Registro(){ Nome = "Teste 1"} });

        Metodo2(new ClasseTeste(){ Obj = new Registro(){ Nome = "Teste 2"} });

        //Metodo3(new ClasseTeste());

    }


    public static void Metodo<T>(IBase<T> parametro) where T: class,IRegistro
    {
        string nome = parametro.GetObj().Nome;
        Console.WriteLine(nome);
    }

    public static void Metodo2(IBase<IRegistro> parametro)
    {
        string nome = parametro.GetObj().Nome;
        Console.WriteLine(nome);
    }

    public static void Metodo3(Teste<IRegistro> parametro)
    {
        string nome = parametro.GetObj().Nome;
        Console.WriteLine(nome);
    }
}

public interface IRegistro
{
    string Nome {get;set;}
}

public class Registro : IRegistro
{
    public string Nome {get;set;}
}


public interface IBase<out T> where T : class, IRegistro
{
    //T Obj{get;set;} //Erro (O Parametro T precisa ser invariante. T é Covariante
    T GetObj ();

    //void MetodoX(T obj); //Erro (O Parametro T precisa ser invariante. T é Covariante
}

public abstract class Teste<T> : IBase<T> where T : class, IRegistro
{
    public T Obj {get;set;}

    public T GetObj ()
    {
        return this.Obj;
    }
}

public class ClasseTeste : Teste<Registro>
{

}
```

[DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3LAcTq)

> O Método que espera `IBase<IRegistro>` passa a aceitar `ClasseTeste`, porém na interface eu não posso declarar propriedades ou métodos com parâmetros do tipo genérico.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se mudar esta linha funciona:

```
public class ClasseTeste : Teste<IRegistro>
```

Outra possibilidade é fazer com que os parâmetros de `Metodo2()` e `Metodo3()` sejam:

```
IBase<Registro>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Generics/Self.cs).

Não há variância em tipos genéricos. Então não pode aceitar `IRegistro` e mandar `Registro` como faz com tipos "simples", ou seja, `Teste<Registro>` não é derivado de `Teste<IRegistro>`, apenas `Registro` é derivado de `IRegistro`.

Quando usa o `T` não estamos falando de herança, apenas de polimorfismo paramétrico, o compilador cria uma indireção para acessar a instância real. Quando usa `IBase<IRegistro>` ele tentará acessar um objeto `IRegistro` que não existe, então só pode ser o `IBase<Registro>`. A não ser que diga que quer a interface na declaração do tipo concreto, aí o compilador sabe que pode haver uma herança no tipo genérico.

Uma coisa que muitos não entendem que usar um tipo faz com que qualquer acesso ao objeto só possa ser feito em membros daquele tipo. Experimenta receber um objeto qualquer como `object` e tente acessar um membro desse objeto que não seja os membros públicos do tipo `Object`. Não dá. Tudo está lá, você sabe disso, mas o compilador não. Ele só consegue garantir a segurança de tipos se você programador garantir que só acessará os membros do tipo `Object`. E o jeito de garantir isso para o compilador é não usando (ele não deixa usar).

Então quando você diz que vai receber `Registro` mas passa um `IRegistro` nada garante que o objeto que é certamente um `IRegistro` seja um `Registro`, pode ser um `Registro2` que se conforma com `IRegistro`, mas não é igual ao `Registro`. `Teste<>` pode acessar quaisquer membros de `Registro`, mas se ele receber um `Registro2` que não tem algum membro que `Registro` dará erro e quebrará a segurança de tipos.

Eu sei, você sabe que tudo estará ok, estamos vendo isso no código, um compilador que só gere executável monolítico analisando todo fonte que o gera pode fazer isso, apesar de ser uma operação complexa e cara, mas um compilador normal que não tem essa garantia não tem como saber se é seguro.

Comment: `"Então quando você diz que vai receber Registro mas passa um IRegistro nada garante que o objeto que é certamente um IRegistro seja um Registro"` Não seria o contrário: digo que vou receber um `IRegistro` e passo um `Registro`. Se `Registro` implementa `IRegistro` não deveria ser garantido?!

Comment: Entendi sobre a variância, dei uma lida nesse material: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/variance-in-generic-interfaces e alterei o código de forma que passe a aceitar a conversão dos tipos com uma interface covariante, porém não posso declarar propriedades e nem métodos que recebam parâmetros do tipo genérico. (Editei a pergunta)

Comment: Minha intenção era ter uma classe que não fosse genérica, recebendo um objeto genérico como parâmetro, mas não foi possível. A definição de covariância que consegui fazer também não me atendeu. Terminei por fazer a classe genérica também. Obrigado pela atenção =]